# SQL Server : how to split fullname into first and last name and show only first 100 characters for last name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below is the select statement. I'm trying to split the `[Display name]` column into `Firstname` and `Lastname`. But when I try to insert the data into the destination table, I get an error

> Data Truncation error

The problem is with the `Lastname` column in the destination table, it only stores 50 characters. I need to only insert first 20 characters of the last name.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(DisplayName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', DisplayName) - 1) AS [FirstName],
    SUBSTRING(DisplayName, CHARINDEX(' ', DisplayName) + 1, LEN(DisplayName)) AS [LastName]
FROM
    [Destination_Table]
WHERE 
    VoidFlag = 0
    AND ControlPlanCode = @ControlPlan
```

This is the result from the above select :

```
FirstName   LastName
-------------------------------------------
Lynn        Trepanier
Becky       Simonds
Mary        Bell
Lynn        Trepanier
Enrollment  Services Enrollment Services
Wendy       Ferenc
Patrick     McGrath
Kevin       Weishaar
Benefit     Configuration Service Benefit Configuration Service
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING(string, start, length)`  Therefore: `SUBSTRING(DisplayName, CHARINDEX(' ', DisplayName) + 1, 20)`

Comment: What do you propose should be the result for `Benefit Configuration Service Benefit Configuration Service`

Comment: Suggested reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(DisplayName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', DisplayName) - 1) AS [FirstName],
    case when LEN(DisplayName) -CHARINDEX(' ', DisplayName) <= 50 then
        SUBSTRING(DisplayName, CHARINDEX(' ', DisplayName) + 1, LEN(DisplayName) -CHARINDEX(' ', DisplayName) ) 
    else
         SUBSTRING(DisplayName, CHARINDEX(' ', DisplayName) + 1,50 ) 
     end 
    AS [LastName]
FROM
    [Destination_Table]
```

First, cut the text to the correct length (`LEN(DisplayName) -CHARINDEX(' ', DisplayName)` )
Secondly, test the length of the truncated text. If it is greater than 50, only cut out 50 characters